# How to get most recent balance for every user and its corresponding dates

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, max

I have a table called `balances`. I want to get the most recent balance for each user, forever every financial year and its corresponding date it was updated.

| name | balance | financial_year | date_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 20 | 2021 | 2021-04-03 |
| Bob | 58 | 2019 | 2019-11-13 |
| Bob | 43 | 2019 | 2022-01-24 |
| Bob | -4 | 2019 | 2019-12-04 |
| James | 92 | 2021 | 2021-09-11 |
| James | 86 | 2021 | 2021-08-18 |
| James | 33 | 2019 | 2019-03-24 |
| James | 46 | 2019 | 2019-02-12 |
| James | 59 | 2019 | 2019-08-12 |

So my desired output would be:

| name | balance | financial_year | date_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 20 | 2021 | 2021-04-03 |
| Bob | 43 | 2019 | 2022-01-24 |
| James | 92 | 2021 | 2021-09-11 |
| James | 59 | 2019 | 2019-08-12 |

I've attempted this but found that using max() sometimes does not work since I use it across multiple columns

```
SELECT name, max(balance), financial_year, max(date_updated)
FROM balances
group by name, financial_year
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select NAME 
      ,BALANCE  
      ,FINANCIAL_YEAR   
      ,DATE_UPDATED
from  (
       select t.*
             ,row_number() over(partition by name, financial_year order by date_updated desc) as rn
       from   t
       ) t
where  rn = 1
```

| NAME | BALANCE | FINANCIAL_YEAR | DATE_UPDATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 43 | 2019 | 24-JAN-22 |
| Bob | 20 | 2021 | 03-APR-21 |
| James | 59 | 2019 | 12-AUG-19 |
| James | 92 | 2021 | 11-SEP-21 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LwctqamN?hide=12)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you use `max()` across multiple columns but the fact, that max() returns the maximum value. In your example, the highest balance of Bob in financial year 2019 was 58. The 'highest' (last) date_updated was 2022-01-24, but at this time the balance was 43.

What you're looking for is the balance at the time the balance was updated last within a financial year per user, that is something like

```
SELECT b.name, b.financial_year, b.balance, b.date_updated
  FROM balances b
  INNER JOIN (SELECT name, financial_year, max(date_updated) last_updated
                FROM balances GROUP BY name, financial_year) u
          ON b.name = u.name AND b.financial_year = u.financial_year AND b.date_updated = u.last_updated;
```